# This property cannot be set after writing has started! on a C# WebRequest Object

Tags: c#

I want to reuse a WebRequest object so that cookies and session would be saved for later request to the server. Below is my code. If i use Post function twice on the second time at

> request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

it will throw an exception

> This property cannot be set after writing has started!

But as you can see

> dataStream.Close();

Should close the writing process! Anybody knows what's going on?

```
static WebRequest request;

public MainForm()
{
    request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/admin/admin.php");
}

static string Post(string url, string data) 
{
    request.Method = "POST";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    request.Abort();
    return responseFromServer;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot reuse the WebRequest. Take the returned [HttpWebResponse.Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies(v=VS.100).aspx), construct a new WebRequest and fill the [HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=VS.100).aspx). (You need to assign a CookieContainer in the first request to get Cookies returned.)

Comment: What about sessions? (is it the same with cookie?)

Comment: Sessions are usually implemented using cookies.

Comment: I though that php sessions are a server side thing! so they are base on cookie?

Comment: PHP sessions depend on a PHP Session ID. This is usually transmitted as cookie or appended to the query string.