# VB.net HTTP POST request

Tags: vb.net

I realize that there have been several similar posts on this topic, but I haven't found a solution yet. I would like to send the data in the field below with a POST request.

[image with search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRXs6.png)

Here is the code I have done so far.

```
Dim result = ""
        Dim URL = "http://derogations/index.php"

        'Create a New WebClient instance.
        Dim myWebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim LeMessage As String
        LeMessage = "filtre_statut=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_client=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_type=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_demandeur=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_validateur=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_recherche=RATNOV0025AB"
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

        'Display the headers in the request
        MsgBox(myWebClient.Headers.ToString())

        'Apply ASCII Encoding to obtain the string as a byte array.
        Dim byteArray() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(LeMessage)

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate)

        Dim req = CType(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
        req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        req.Method = "POST"
        'req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        req.KeepAlive = False
        req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10
        'req.Timeout = -1;

        Try
            Using writer As New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
                writer.WriteLine(byteArray)
            End Using
            Using resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
                Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
                    result = sr.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            result = MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set the HTTP1.0 as protocol? While trying to set TLS12? Why are you setting `KeepAlive = False`? Why are you setting `AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True` when this is the default? Do yourself a favor, use HttpClient to send a [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent) object to your endpoint. Check whether this service requires a User-Agent header set to accept (and evaluate) requests. -- You didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: If you're interested, see: [Understand HttpWebRequest in KeepAlive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49609131/7444103)

Comment: Ok, sorry i have mixed several posts and I got a little lost in the many information. My question is a bit broad, but how do I send a POST request with multiple parameters? Do I need to authenticate? I'm just looking to fill in the search box to search for a component.

Comment: This is what a request looks like to display the search result. X and Y change with each request.  [http://derogations/index.php?filtre_statut=*&filtre_client=&filtre_type=*&filtre_demandeur=*&filtre_validateur=*&filtre_recherche=CODECOMPONENT&x=5&y=12](http://derogations/index.php?filtre_statut=*&filtre_client=&filtre_type=*&filtre_demandeur=*&filtre_validateur=*&filtre_recherche=CODECOMPONENT&x=5&y=12)

Comment: Here is the answer of the topic : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001929/vb-net-open-a-web-page-with-the-form-field-filled-in/67056645#67056645)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested in the result. Here is a topic with the solution.

[VB.net Open a web page with the form field filled in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001929/vb-net-open-a-web-page-with-the-form-field-filled-in)