# VB.net Open a web page with the form field filled in

Tags: vb.net

[Resolved] I'm looking to open a web page with the form field filled in. For that I would like that when I click on the component of the listView below, it redirects me to the web page with the form filled with the name of the component.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NSIb.png)

I searched a lot but couldn't find a topic like mine.

EDIT : I just found a code that seems interesting to me

```
Private Function Post_request(ByVal url As String, ByVal data As String, Optional ByVal cookies As String = "", Optional ByVal proxy As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal proxyport As Integer = Nothing, Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = 30000, Optional ByVal login As String = "", Optional ByVal pass As String = "") As String
        Dim reader As IO.StreamReader
        Dim writer As IO.StreamWriter
        Dim res As String = ""
        Try
            Dim hwebrequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url) ' on crée la requete web à partir de l'url
            If proxy <> "" Then
                Dim hproxy As WebProxy
                hproxy = New WebProxy(proxy, proxyport)
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = hproxy
            End If
            If login <> "" Then
                Dim hcredential As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(login, pass)
                hwebrequest.Credentials = hcredential
            End If
            If cookies <> "" Then
                hwebrequest.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer
                hwebrequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(New Uri(url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("/", 8))), cookies)
            End If
            hwebrequest.Method = "POST" 'on defini la methode à utiliser
            hwebrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 'on defini le type de contenu de la requete
            hwebrequest.ContentLength = data.Length 'on defini la taille des données à envoyé
            writer = New IO.StreamWriter(hwebrequest.GetRequestStream) 'on crée un objet streamwriter qui va nous permettre d'envoyer nos données
            writer.Write(data) 'on ecrit les données
            writer.Close() 'on ferme l'objet streamwriter
            Dim hwebresponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = hwebrequest.GetResponse 'on crée un objet de reponse a notre requete 
            reader = New IO.StreamReader(hwebresponse.GetResponseStream) 'on redefini notre streamreader avec la reponse à la requete en argument 
            res = reader.ReadToEnd() 'on renvoie l'ensemble du resultat 
            reader.Close() 'on ferme l'objet 
            Return res
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message.ToString
        End Try
    End Function
```

But I don't know what data I should send. Do I have to send data this way ?

```
 Dim LeMessage As String
        LeMessage = "?filtre_statut=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_client=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_type=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_demandeur=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_validateur=*"
        LeMessage &= "&filtre_recherche=RATNOV0025AB"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just succeeded, here is the result for those who need:

```
Private Sub BtnDerogation_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDerogation.Click
        If lvListeComposantsOF.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
            Dim LeMessage As String
            LeMessage = "filtre_statut=*"
            LeMessage &= "&filtre_client=*"
            LeMessage &= "&filtre_type=*"
            LeMessage &= "&filtre_demandeur=*"
            LeMessage &= "&filtre_validateur=*"
            LeMessage &= "&filtre_recherche=" & Trim(lvListeComposantsOF.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text)
            Dim page As String = Post_request("http://website/", LeMessage)

            Form1.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = page
            Form1.Visible = True
        Else
            ErrorMessage("Veuillez sélectionner une ligne pour afficher la page web des dérogations")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function Post_request(ByVal url As String, ByVal data As String, Optional ByVal cookies As String = "", Optional ByVal proxy As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal proxyport As Integer = Nothing, Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = 30000, Optional ByVal login As String = "", Optional ByVal pass As String = "") As String
        Dim reader As IO.StreamReader
        Dim writer As IO.StreamWriter
        Dim res As String = ""
        Try
            Dim hwebrequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url) ' on crée la requete web à partir de l'url
            If proxy <> "" Then
                Dim hproxy As WebProxy
                hproxy = New WebProxy(proxy, proxyport)
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = hproxy
            End If
            If login <> "" Then
                Dim hcredential As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(login, pass)
                hwebrequest.Credentials = hcredential
            End If
            If cookies <> "" Then
                hwebrequest.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer
                hwebrequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(New Uri(url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("/", 8))), cookies)
            End If
            hwebrequest.Method = "POST" 'on defini la methode à utiliser
            hwebrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 'on defini le type de contenu de la requete
            hwebrequest.ContentLength = data.Length 'on defini la taille des données à envoyé
            writer = New IO.StreamWriter(hwebrequest.GetRequestStream) 'on crée un objet streamwriter qui va nous permettre d'envoyer nos données
            writer.Write(data) 'on ecrit les données
            writer.Close() 'on ferme l'objet streamwriter
            Dim hwebresponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = hwebrequest.GetResponse 'on crée un objet de reponse a notre requete 
            reader = New IO.StreamReader(hwebresponse.GetResponseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) 'on redefini notre streamreader avec la reponse à la requete en argument 
            res = reader.ReadToEnd() 'on renvoie l'ensemble du resultat 
            reader.Close() 'on ferme l'objet 
            Return res
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message.ToString
        End Try
    End Function
```